# Retrofit can't keep value out of its own method

Tags: android, retrofit

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(URL).build();
api api = restAdapter.create(api.class);
api.get(value, new Callback<model>(){

            @Override
            public void success(model model, Response response) {
                //get value of a here.
                a=model.getA();

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I want to get value a outside retrofit function.but it's invalid.
I have tried final,but it need to give value first(can't get value from getA()) 
or final in where we getA() (but it still can't use outside because it is a local variable.)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not about getting value from `Retrofit`. when you execute your `get` function, you are trying to show `Toast` immediately but your request is asynchronous and you should wait until getting response from your server. you should change your code to something like this:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(URL).build();
api api = restAdapter.create(api.class);
api.get(value, new Callback<model>(){

            @Override
            public void success(model model, Response response) {
                //get value of a here.
                a=model.getA();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

or you can use synchronous request instead but as far as you are on main thread, avoid using synchronous request because it'll cause you app to freeze and show ANR error.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer me so quickly.
but i acually need to use the value from retrofit outside that instead of inside

for example i want to clicklistener using the value, but i need to write it on other method like oncreate() to initial some other value.
i mean ....isn't there any way to write outside?i really can't believe it OTZ

Comment: there is no problem with using that variable outside of callback but you have to make sure that you already retrieved value from server and not using it before getting any response from server.

Comment: I have make a try like:toast what it(for example: a) get from server(inside retrofit). it works,but when I call a again outside, nullpointer happen with a that just toast successly to me.so I'm sure server is ok.
I have no idea whether version might lead it or not.

Comment: there is nothing wrong. look, you are requesting some data from your server, you must wait until you retrieve data from server otherwise you'll face null pointer exception. you should call your functions that needs this data from your callback to make sure that you already have those values. ok?

Comment: I think there are something about usXD.how can a get value from server,and toast success,not finish callback?Actually,my biggist question is   is "a" possible back to null after i toast successly,unless retrofit function have some speicial ability,don't it = =

Comment: of course not.
It'll have value for rest of its life.

Comment: That is my real question.I lost the value I toast success,it's theoretically impossible OTZ